# Jquery Remove doesn't entirely remove the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Based on the Jquery documentation .remove will remove the element and nested html elements inside the parent tag.

Using the Jquery example

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$( ".hello" ).remove();
```

will give

```
<div class="container">
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

However, I maybe doing this incorrectly but i need to use jquery to move an element.

If i do the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>

var container = $(".container")[0].outerHTML;
$(".container").remove();
$(".test").append(container);
```

This will make a copy of the container including the parent element, remove the html elements and then append .test with the data. If i then try to add an element after the textarea like this:

```
$("textarea").after("<p>abc123</p>");
```

Instead of applying the paragraph to the textarea that is left it applies it to where the original textarea should be and also to the new textarea.

Does anyone know if this is due to the way i have done this or if there is a way around?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to get to.

Comment: _"Instead of applying the paragraph to the textarea that is left it applies it to where the original textarea should be and also to the new textarea."_ Not for me it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FBC2A/

Comment: @KellyJAndrews basically we are using a templating system that won't allow us to seperate components. So i'm having to remove them using jquery and then position the div elsewhere

Comment: @j08691 your right. i will take a look at my original code and see if i can get a jsfiddle to replicate as this maybe an issue with my code

Comment: @j08691 not sure what the issue is here but it certainly something wrong with my code so thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append()` moves the element, you don't have to `remove()` it at all

```
$(".test").append($(".container"));
```

Comment: your right append will copy the .container however i need to move the .container and remove it from it's original location. Sorry i wasn't that clear

Comment: @LiamSorsby - That's exactly what append does when called on an existing element, it doesn't create another element, it just moves the one you have, you don't have to remove anything.

Comment: I've not a clue what i tried, but that does actually work sorry i will try this see what happens

Comment: as this has helped with removing unnecessary code i will mark this as correct as this seems to be an issue with my code and nothing else. Thank you for your help